# s'en prendre à, s'attaquer à

Tags: expressions

Ma copie de la bible montre, comme elle semble toujours le faire, des irrégularités par rapport à d'autres traductions quant à Gen 37, 21. Ici Ruben veut sauver la vie à Joseph :

[image: Ne nous en prenons pas à sa vie]

Je trouve dans le Wiktionnaire l'expression « [s'en prendre à](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%E2%80%99en_prendre_%C3%A0) » : *(1) attribuer à quelqu'un une faute ; (2) « par extension » s'attaquer à*. C'est la première fois que je la vois mais Ngrams la [confirme](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=s%27en%20prendre%20%C3%A0&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cs%27en%20prendre%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0).

Cette expression traduit l'hébreu לֹ֥א נַכֶּ֖נּוּ נָֽפֶשׁ « nég. nous-ferons-se-frapper-à-lui [la] vie ». À mon sens donc les deux phrases s'alignent.

Néanmoins d'autres traductions l'interprètent [de diverses façons](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2037%3A21&version=LSG;BDS;SG21) :

> Ne lui ôtons pas la vie. (Louis Segond 1910)
>
> N’attentons pas à sa vie! (Louis Segond 2007)
>
> Ne portons pas atteinte à sa vie! (La Bible du Semeur 1999)

Qu'est-ce qui motiverait un autre choix que « s'en prendre à » ? Est-ce que c'est rare ? Vieilli ? Inexact vu la glose de l'originel ? Ou toutes ces traductions sont-elles équivalentes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

« S'en prendre à » n’est pas une expression vraiment rare, en tout cas je l’utilise parfois. L'expression signifie d’après le dictionnaire Larousse:

> Critiquer quelqu'un, le rendre responsable, l'attaquer.

Ici, dans ce contexte, « s'en prendre à » est bien équivalent à « attaquer » ou « porter atteinte à ». Cependant je pense que dans cette expression, il y a généralement en plus cet aspect de reproche ou de colère contre la personne/chose contre laquelle on « s'en prend ».

Par exemple :

> Ne t'en prends pas au chat, il n'a rien fait !

signifie que la personne s'attaque au chat dans un acte de colère même si le pauvre chat ne faisait peut-être que passer par là.

Ne connaissant pas ce passage de la Bible, je ne peux malheureusement pas expliquer ce choix de traduction par rapport aux autres.

Comment: Cela a du sens. Je dirais que cette interprétation est donc la bonne : dans ce contexte les jeunes hommes sont jaloux de leur frère qui a rêvé être leur seigneur. Il s'agit alors de représailles mesquines. Merci !